# Extract all numbers of N digits from a string in C

Tags: c, pointers

I want to get all numbers from a specific string but, these numbers **could be more than one digit long** as (15, 587, ... exc). Here is what I did "my own code":

```
int firstIndxOfNumb(char* str, int startIndx, int len) {
    int i, val;
    i = startIndx;
    while (str[i] && i < len) {
        val = str[i];
        if (isdigit(val))
            return i;
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}

int lastIndxOfNumb(char* exp, int len, int indx1){
    int i, curr;
    for(i = indx1; i < len; i++){
        curr = exp[i];
        if(!isdigit(curr)){
            return --i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int getNumb(char* exp, int len, int* indx1){
    int indx2 = lastIndxOfNumb(exp, len, *indx1);

    printf("indx1:%d\tindx2:%d\n", *indx1, indx2);

    char temp[indx2-*indx1];
    strncpy(temp, exp+*indx1, (size_t) (indx2-*indx1+1));
    *indx1 = firstIndxOfNumb(exp, indx2+1, len);
    return atoi(temp);
}

void main() {
    char *s = "())(15*59";
    int len = strlen(s);
    int indx1;
    indx1 = firstIndxOfNumb(s, 0, len);
    printf("%d\n", getNumb(s, len, &indx1));
    printf("\n%d", getNumb(s, len, &indx1));

}
```

And the goal is getting the two numbers (15, 59). The first call was okay but, the second is not "infinite-loop" with values **index1:7** okay **index2:0** isn't okay! Can you help me to make it working .....
The values are printed by `printf(..);` in `getNum();` function ....

Comment: you could use `strtoi` instead of `atoi`. It returns the number _and_ the number of characters read. A time-saver for you.

Comment: is there no negative number in string?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY There is

Comment: But you are not searching for the `'-'`.

Comment: Yes ... I was going to do it in the next step after finishing positive numbers only ...

Comment: Could you tell me how can I do it, please?

Comment: First of all, we need to change API.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes .... then?

Comment: I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Mr, @BLUEPIXY ... :)

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getNumb` can be simplified as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int getNumb(char **sp){
    char *p = *sp;
    while(*p && !isdigit((unsigned char)*p))//skip not digit
        ++p;
    if(!*p)
        return -1;//not find numbers (Don't include negative numbers as extract numbers)
    int ret = strtol(p, &p, 10);
    *sp = p;
    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
    char *s = "())(15*59";
    char *sp = s;
    printf("%d\n", getNumb(&sp));
    printf("%d\n", getNumb(&sp));
}
```

---

When it contains a negative number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool getNum(char **sp, int *v /* out */){
    char *p = *sp;
    while(*p && !isdigit((unsigned char)*p) && (*p!='-' || !isdigit((unsigned char)p[1])) )//skip not number
        ++p;
    if(!*p)
        return false;//not find numbers
    *v = strtol(p, &p, 10);
    *sp = p;
    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    char *s = "())(15*59+++-123,-2)";
    char *sp = s;
    int v;
    while(getNum(&sp, &v))
        printf("%d\n", v);
}
```

Comment: superb simplification.